# Different users, different desktop managers

Tags: 11.04, users, desktop-environments

I'm using Ubuntu 11.04 since it was released, and, as many, i "kinda" like unity so far, but, i want to know if there is any way to have 2 users, one with Unity and the other with classic gnome? Is there any way to configure users like this?

Ty.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the same account for both. Just log out to the login screen and in the session menu pick *Ubuntu Classic* when you want classic Gnome, and *Ubuntu* when you want Unity:
[image]

[(Image source)](http://www.multimediaboom.com/ubuntu-11-04-natty-screenshot-review-whats-new-features-video/)

Answer (score 2):

Just create both users and at the login screen choose the user you want to login and select the desktop environment at the bottom of the screen.